# Why don't functions inside immediately invoked function expressions require a name?

Tags: javascript, iife

The code below gives the following error:
**VM502:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name**
and I assume it doesn't work because, as per the error message, function declarations require a function name.

```js
function (){
var a = 'dog';
console.log(a);
}
```

The second code below doesn't produce an error, but gives "dog", because it is not a function declaration but an immediately invoked function expression...

```js
(function(){
var a ='dog';
console.log(a);
})()
```

Why don't functions inside iife require a name?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unnamed_function_statement

Comment: Because at top-level `function` starts a named function definition.

Comment: "*Why don't functions inside iife require a name?*" the IIFE *is* the function "inside the IIFE" you mention. So it's a bit redundant and confusing to call it that. The reason why function expressions don't require a name is simple - they are function expressions and function expressions don't require a name.